# nginx + wordpress + permalink - working except /feed/

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks, php

I've a pretty much working web server, running on Debian 6.0.3, nginx + php-fpm, with wordpress as my blog backend. I've done the setup using bash script from [lempstack](https://github.com/aatishnn/lempstack)

Permalink is working for my pages and posts except feed. I get 404 from `mydomain.com/feed/` but it works if I've already login, which is not what I wanted.

I'm trying to debug the redirect, wordpress is the one throwing 404. I've tried variation of nginx site config but still the same outcome. Has anyone face the same problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue, has nothing to do with nginx or php. Apparently if there's no post at all, accessing rss feed with return 404. It works when I login, as I have a few private posts.